# is </img> tag for embedding Title of Image?

Tags: html, css, image

Just wondering why do we need `</img>`?

For example, `<img src="myurl.com/pic.gif" />` is enough for showing image but we can also do thing like this:

`<img src="myurl.com/pic.gif"> This is my image</img>`, then it will show the text "This is my image" next to the picture.

so my question is:

is  tag for embedding Title of Image?

But we can do the same thing like this:

```
<img src="myurl.com/pic.gif" /> This is my Image.
```

Comment: `img` is selfclosing tag, every text you write before/next will show of course.

Comment: `title` is an attribute, what you write inside tags is the content of that tag, but `img` is not that kind of tag of course.

Comment: I don't think you even need the closing '/' anymore. As far as I know they are optional in HTML5. Anyone clarify this?

Comment: Yes. `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` means, you dont need to do stuff like `<br />` or `<img.. />`

Comment: @BatuZet — The `/` for empty element syntax is only for XHTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to put this code through an HTML5 validator, it will say it's invalid and that the closing tag `</img>` is not needed. You are right that all you need is `<img ... />`.

<s>In the past, all tags were declared as `<tag></tag>`</s> In XHTML, you may see `<img></img>` but no content will appear between the tags.

So you are right, you should simply use `<img .../> Some Text Here` to display text next to any image.

Comment: So it's not treated differently at all even for accessibility?

Comment: `<img>...</img>` isn't even valid in HTML5, and the stuff between the tags is *not* treated as a title, in any case.

Comment: *In the past, all tags were declared as `<tag></tag>`* — That isn't true. HTML has *always* has `<img>` elements with no end tag, and the `<img />` syntax for HTML didn't even appear until XHTML 1 about a decade later.

Comment: @quentin fixed it. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

According to HTML 4.01 standard it's empty element: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/objects.html#h-13.2

> The IMG element has no content (...)

Moreover, you shouldn't close it unless using XHTML (`<img>` not `<img/>`).

Answer (score 1):

> Just wondering why do we need `</img>`?

You do not. `img` is an EMPTY element. The end tag is forbidden in HTML.

In XHTML you may use either `<img></img>` or `<img />` (the latter syntax is required for HTML Compatible XHTML) but you may not have content between `<img>` and `</img>`.

> `<img src="myurl.com/pic.gif"> This is my image</img>`, then it will show the text "This is my image" next to the picture.

As far as the browser is concerned, this means:

1. Start of img element
2. img element has a forbidden end tag, so also end of img
3. Some text
4. Invalid end tag which is ignored

Comment: Forbidden in which version of HTML?

Comment: @CodeBlend — Every version of HTML.

Comment: Quote source to back this up please

Comment: @CodeBlend — Defined as empty: [`<!ELEMENT IMG    - O EMPTY --  Embedded image -->`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#img)

Comment: so </img> is kind of deprecated tag or something like that?

Comment: @CodeBlend — Defined as empty: [`<!ELEMENT IMG - O EMPTY                -- Embedded image -->`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.2)

Comment: @CodeBlend — [Tag omission in text/html:
No end tag.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element)

Comment: @CodeBlend — Defined as empty: [`<!ELEMENT IMG    - O EMPTY>`](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_9.html#SEC9.1)

Comment: @CodeBlend — [The IMG element is empty: it has no closing tag.](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in the img tag, you cannot set a title that will appear next to the image.

Only title, which will be the text of the toolltip above the image and alt which will be displayed if there is some problem with getting the image.